# Read file to array with <> without adding newline to last line

Tags: perl

I'm trying to slurp a text file into an array using the diamond operators by doing
`my @array = <$filehandle>;` but this always appends a \n to the last line in the file whether it is there or not. Is there a simple way to not have the last line end with \n if it's not in the original file? I've tried slurping into a scalar (with `undef $/`)and splitting the scalar into an array on the assumption I could pop the last element and if it's blank assume the final line finished with \n but the last element is always the last line regardless of whether whether it has a newline or not. I would've assumed splitting "hello\nworld\n" would give me an array of 3 elements with the last being blank but it doesn't, also this seems a very expensive way to get rid of a dangling newline. I can't use chomp because I don't know if the last line of the file should have a newline or not.

EDIT: In response to Ikegami claim that my premise is false I present the following code and output, maybe I'm missing something.
The files test2 contains "first line\nsecond line"

```
my $file = 'test2';
my @lines = &slurp($file);
for (@lines) { print "-$_-\n"; }

sub slurp {
my $f = shift;
open(my $fh, '<', $f) or die $!;
my @ary = <$fh>;
return @ary;
}
```

The output is

```
-first line
-
-second line
-
```

When I change the text in test2 to 'first line\nsecond line\n' it outputs

```
-first line
-
-second line
-
-
-
```

I can't deny the code you posted produced the same output on my machine but then again this is what I'm getting on my machine and there's quite clearly a a newline after second line.

UPDATE: It seems the newline is being added by vim, not perl.

Comment: Text files should always end in a newline anyways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *Is there a simple way to not have the last line end with \n if it's not in the original file?*

The code you provided already does that.

---

> *this always appends a \n to the last line in the file*

No, `<>` does not add anything.

```
$ printf 'a\nb\nc\n' |
    perl -MData::Dumper -e'$Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1; print( Dumper( [ <> ] ) );'
$VAR1 = [
          "a\n",
          "b\n",
          "c\n"
        ];

$ printf 'a\nb\nc' |
    perl -MData::Dumper -e'$Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1; print( Dumper( [ <> ] ) );'
$VAR1 = [
          "a\n",
          "b\n",
          "c"
        ];
```

Your claim is simply not true.

---

> *I present the following code and output*

It does not output what you claim it does.

```
$ cat >a.pl
my $file = 'test2';
my @lines = &slurp($file);
for (@lines) { print "-$_-\n"; }

sub slurp {
my $f = shift;
open(my $fh, '<', $f) or die $!;
my @ary = <$fh>;
return @ary;
}

$ printf 'first line\nsecond line\n' >test2

$ perl a.pl
-first line
-
-second line
-

$ printf 'first line\nsecond line' >test2

$ perl a.pl
-first line
-
-second line-
```

---

> I would've assumed splitting "hello\nworld\n" would give me an array of 3 elements

It does if you use

```perl
split( /\n/, "hello\nworld\n", -1 )   # "hello", "world", ""
```

---

> *I can't use chomp*

`chomp` works perfectly fine even if the final LF is missing.

---

> *I could pop the last element and if it's blank*

Are you asking for the following?

```perl
my $file = do { local $/; <> };
my @lines = split( /\n/, $file, -1 );
pop( @lines ) if @lines && $lines[-1] eq "";
```

That can be simplified to

```perl
my $file = do { local $/; <> };
my @lines = split( /\n/, $file );
```

or even

```perl
chomp( my @lines = <> );
```

---

Given an array of lines (such as the one returned by `<>`), you can use the following to check if the last line is LF-terminated:

```perl
my $has_final_lf = @lines ? substr( $lines[-1], -1 ) eq "\n" : 1;
```

You didn't ask for this, but maybe it's what you want?

Comment: I've edited my question as I wasn't able to include the code in a comment but I'm not wanting to remove LFs I'm simply wanting to slurp a file and push it onto an array. If the original array has 'one <load file=two.txt'> three' I would like it to read 'one two three' assuming two.txt has the string 'two' and no linefeeds but there is always a linefeed added after the insert. When I manually put the text 'two' into the new array instead of slurping it from a file there is no new line added. I've updated my question to show the behaviour with minimal code.

Comment: Your claims about what the program in your update outputs are untrue. I've added a section to address this to my question, but it otherwise stands.

Comment: OK it seems when I create the file using print it works as expected and when I use vim it displays the extra \n even though editing both files in vim shows no difference. It seems the extra newline is coming from vim not perl. Should I accept you answer or just delete my question?

Comment: `vim` always places a terminating LF as it should. I think what's confusing you is that `vim` doesn't allow you to place your cursor after the last line like some other editors do, and you've been compensating by adding a blank line, which `vim` properly terminates with a LF.